# excel vba to copy/paste data fron another sheet if conditions match

Tags: excel, vba

[Sheet saskaita faktura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQpWq.png)
[Sheet darbinis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNHmK.png)

hopping to find help here. Can't get data from one sheet to another using conditions.
My question:
I will use example :
if sheet1 cell d22 = sheet2 column B cells 3(4;5;6;..), then
sheet1 cell P3 data copy and paste to sheet2 column C cells 3(4;5;6;..)

this should happen if i click button.

Thank you in advance.
Darius

Adding code:

```
Sub bandymas()

If Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("d22") = Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D:D") Then
Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("P3").Copy
Sheets("Darbinis").Range ("O:O")
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPaste, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: yoou can format your code : select then ctrl +k

Comment: now i put data by hand and simple if statement formulas to paste in all cells that match the criteria, with macro I'm new in the field.

Comment: ok, you need test cells : cells(y,x)=, or range("D22") = , then you need a loop : for each c in range("A1:A20") if range etc.

Comment: Please post your VBA code where you are trying this so that we can help fix it.

Comment: @Rodger, the code is added in the question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO I added the code in the question. Thank you fopr responding.

Comment: this line If Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("d22") = Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D:D") means cell d22 = entire row D, could you give more details, is d22 must be equal to every cells in row d ?

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO it is data sheet (Darbinis) with alot of data and in some of D column cells will be the data matching with Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("d22") in some not, but when it is matching I want to fill column O cells in the same rows as the matching data in column D.

Answer (score 0):

P is the source, o is destination, you can  adjust

```
Sub bandymas()
LastRow = Sheets("Darbinis").Cells(Sheets("Darbinis").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
dim i 
i=0
for each c in Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
    i=i+1
    If Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("d22") = c Then
       Sheets("Darbinis").Range("O" & i) = Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("P3").value  
    endif
next
End Sub
```

Comment: give me some details, i'll fix the function above

Comment: Some thing wrong with :"dim i =0"it is in red color. how can i send example  workbook? it will be more visible what i'm looking for.

Comment: you can add a picture, source destination

Comment: some how nothing happening.. how can i add example picture?

Comment: edit your question and add 2 pictures, first xlsx source and second xlsx destination. It should be enough to answer.

Comment: I added two pictures of the example sheets. I think it is more clear now. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: where should i push?

Comment: sorry for getting back to the question, but I spotted that it puts data with +1 in every next row. The data should be the same, if the code in D column cells is the same.

Comment: maybe it pastes the formula, check the fix

Comment: it does not help. it pastes every next row with +1.

Comment: give me an example, i dont understand next row +1

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, code looks:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Range("P3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

lastrow = Sheets("Darbinis").Cells(Sheets("Darbinis").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i
i = 0
For Each c In Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D1:D" & lastrow)
    i = i + 1
        If Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("d22") = c Then
       Sheets("Darbinis").Range("O" & i) = Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("P5").Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

then it work as it suposed.