# excel vba to copy/paste data fron another sheet if conditions match (but not +1)

Tags: vba, excel

almost solved question, but still need help.
Here is code:

```
Sub bandymas()
LastRow = Sheets("Darbinis").Cells(Sheets("Darbinis").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
dim i 
i=0
for each c in Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
    i=i+1
    If Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("d22") = c Then
       Sheets("Darbinis").Range("O" & i) = Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("P3")  
    endif
next
End Sub
```

Everything the same but not add +1 if the value in Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D1:D") is the same.

Thank you in advance.
Darius

Comment: already posted question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972372/excel-vba-to-copy-paste-data-fron-another-sheet-if-conditions-match

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, due to regular formulas in the P3 cell it adds +1, but if I firstly do a paste value move and change source location then it works, code looks:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Range("P3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

lastrow = Sheets("Darbinis").Cells(Sheets("Darbinis").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i
i = 0
For Each c In Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D1:D" & lastrow)
    i = i + 1
        If Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("d22") = c Then
       Sheets("Darbinis").Range("O" & i) = Sheets("Sàskaita-Faktûra").Range("P5").Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

then it work as it suposed.

Answer (score -1):

Cant actually work out whats going wrong! Error message or working but not as expected?

Not sure if it is necessary, but your variables lastRow & i are integers. I'd convert them to strings for use in range referencing: i.e. from

```
for each c in Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
```

to

```
for each c in Sheets("Darbinis").Range("D1:D" & CSTR(lastRow))
```